# Mathematica Manipulate Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Does anybody know how I can use the Manipulate command with the show command. 
Basically, I want to display multiple funcitons on one coordinate system. However, I want only one of them to be "manipulated" (i.e. other should be static). 
I can not sort out how to use Show and Manipulate together. 
Thanks for your help!
HR

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the manipulated variable, `a`, in one of the plots, simply omit it.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[a x, {x, 0, 3.5}],
  ListPlot[{1, 2/a, 3/a}]],
 {{a, 1}, 0, 2}]
```